# How can I pass the viewmodel from Create back to the Edit view in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) //View
{
       PlayerSettingViewModel view = new PlayerSettingViewModel();
       if (id != null)
       {
              AccountDTO model = _AccountsBLL.GetAccountById(id.Value);
              if (model != null)
              {
                    if (model.AccountId != null)
                    {
                        AccountDTO Account = _AccountsBLL.GetAccount(model.AccountId);

                        view = new PlayerSettingViewModel
                        {
                            Id = Account .Id,
                            AccountType = Account.AccountType
                            Username = Account.Username ,
                            Password = Account.Password ,
                        }

                    }
              }
       }
       return View(view);
}
public ActionResult Create(PlayerSettingViewModel view) //Action
{
      ///Passing Data and creating it
      if(model.id > 0)
      {
            return Redirect("Player","Index")//When successfully created
      }else
      {
            return REdirect("Player", "Edit")//When fail to creat
      }
}
```

My question is how do I pass a the View Model data that the user inserted, from Create Action to the Edit Page when the user fail to create the info. This action is to help the user not require to fill in the required field again but only need to reinsert the fill that is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not redirect as the model state will get lost.

In case of failure to save model in the DB, what we do is return the model back to the View and it will get repopulated on the UI like:

```
  //Passing Data and creating it
  if(model.id > 0)
  {
        //When successfully created
  }
  else
  {
        return View("Edit",model); //When fail to creat
  }
```

This will render the Edit view with the data that is posted to Create action populated back in the View.